# I'm trying to make expanding cards using Vue, the problem is that when expanding a card, the cards on the right create an empty space

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make expanding cards using Vue, the problem is that when expanding a card, the cards on the right create an empty space,the entire bottom row goes down, and I just wanted the card directly below it to go down, not all.

This is the way it is currently:
[image: 1]

This is the way I want to:
[image: 2]

Here is the part of the code that I believe controls this, or would it be in the expansion part?

```
<v-container class="pt-0 mt-0">
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex
      xs12
      md6
      lg3
      v-for="stateCard in filteredSearch"
      :key="stateCard.name"
    >
      <MakeTheCard :item="infoCard" />
        
      
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a CSS problem rather than Vue.

One approach is to make a `flex` container with `columns`, each containing X amount of elements.

like so:

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <Card v-for="card in 2" :key="card" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <Card v-for="card in 2" :key="card" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <Card v-for="card in 1" :key="card" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Just made a demo for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-leaf-mv8lp